# Sort and keep count of data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, hashmap

My list of data is like this where I have converted timestamp to an hour, minute, and second and exception that occurred during the time. The data is already in `sorted` manner and so the order will only be changed if the times(hour, minute, and second) are likewise but the exception name is different.

In that case, the data will be sorted in alphabetically order. (for that particular time only)

Expected Output :

```
21:15-21:30 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
21:15-21:30 NullPointerException 2,
22:00-22:15 UserNotFoundException 1,
22:15-22:30 NullPointerException 1,
22:30-22:45 UserNotFoundException 3,
22:45-23:00 UserNotFoundException 1,
23:00-23:15 NullPointerException 1,
23:15-23:30 UserNotFoundException 1,
23:30-23:45 NullPointerException 2,
23:45-00:00 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
00:00-00:15 UserNotFoundException 1,
00:30-00:45 NullPointerException 1,
00:45-01:00 UserNotFoundException 1,
01:00-01:15 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
01:15-01:30 UserNotFoundException 1,
01:30-01:45 NullPointerException 1,
01:45-02:00 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
02:00-02:15 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
02:15-02:30 UserNotFoundException 1,
02:30-02:45 NullPointerException 1,
03:00-03:15 IllegalAgrumentsException 1
```

The data in the following manner.

```
data = 
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 21, 'minute': 27}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 21, 'minute': 27}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 21, 'minute': 27}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 0}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 17}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 33}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 33}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 33}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 22, 'minute': 50}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 23, 'minute': 7}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 23, 'minute': 23}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 23, 'minute': 40}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 23, 'minute': 40}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 23, 'minute': 57}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 0, 'minute': 13}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 0, 'minute': 30}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 0, 'minute': 47}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 1, 'minute': 3}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 1, 'minute': 20}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 1, 'minute': 37}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 1, 'minute': 53}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 2, 'minute': 10}
   {'second': 12, 'data': 'UserNotFoundException', 'hour': 2, 'minute': 27}
   {'second': 52, 'data': 'NullPointerException', 'hour': 2, 'minute': 43}
   {'second': 32, 'data': 'IllegalAgrumentsException', 'hour': 3, 'minute': 0}
```

I have already formatted the data into 15 min range but I am not able to sort the data.and also I need to keep the count of exception data at that time.

I have tried to iterate over the data but I was not able to swap the data if exception name are not alphabetically ordered. How can this be done?

Comment: can understand what does `21:15-21:30` if it means the starting time and the end time then your data would be missing something

Comment: That's how we need to format the data between 15 min time range which will be done once data is sorted and we have got the count @AdamSherif. I have done that part. If you want I can post that code here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data set is time sorted, you can use below function for interval and data aggregation:

```
import time    
Data= [{'second': 12, 'data': 1, 'hour': 21, 'minute': 27},
       {'second': 12, 'data': 2, 'hour': 21, 'minute': 50},
       {'second': 12, 'data': 1, 'hour': 22, 'minute': 28},
       {'second': 12, 'data': 1, 'hour': 23, 'minute': 28},
       {'second': 12, 'data': 'stre', 'hour': 21, 'minute': 28}]

#21:15-21:30 IllegalAgrumentsException 1,
o_data =[]
o_time = []
ot_time = []
agg_data = 0
ind = 0
dataset = {}
except_data = {}
interval = 900
for i in Data:
    time_in_data = '2020-05-17 {}:{}:{}'.format(i['hour'],i['minute'],i['second'])
    time_str =time.strptime(time_in_data,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    try:
        data_value = int(i['data'])
        hh=time.mktime(time_str,)
        ot_time.append(hh)
        if hh<ot_time[ind]+interval:
            agg_data = agg_data + data_value
        else:
            o_data.append(agg_data)
            o_time.append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime( hh)))
            ind +=1
            dataset[o_time[-1]] = o_data[-1]
    except:
        except_data[time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time_str)]= i['data']
print(dataset, except_data)
```

Comment: I have to arrange exceptions also, where are exceptions ?

Comment: please illustrate exceptions  with data entries

Comment: so here exceptions names need to be sorted after it's sorted by date.

Comment: I need the exact output (apart from 15 min formatter)